# Questions about the text of telegram bots

Tags: python, telegram-bot

How to put a large text on the output in a telegram bot, what are the distribution tools

I tried to insert the text as it is, writes that there is an error in the syntax

Comment: Please share your code, so we can get an understanding of what is not working. Although the error message would be really helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use triple quotes or triple double-quotes.

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def start(message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, """texttexttextext

texttexttextext

texttexttextext

texttexttextext""")
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```